# Git dependency errors when using Composer with private VCS repository on IBM i

Tags: bash, git, composer-php, ibm-midrange

More details below, but I'm running into the following error when I issue a `composer install` or `composer update` command on a project which uses a custom VCS repository for an included project.  This is on an IBM i v7r3 system via SSH session.  I've run out of ideas on how to troubleshoot further, so here I am.  Has anyone ever seen this error or have any ideas on how to troubleshoot further?

**Error:**

```
bash-4.4$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 113 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing sshUser/myPackage (v1.0.26): Cloning a2db0666b1


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone gitUser:/opt/git/myPackage.git, git was not found, check that
   it is installed and in your PATH env.

  Could not load program git:
        Dependent module /usr/local/zendphp7/lib/libz.so.1(shr_64.o) could not be loaded.

        File /usr/local/zendphp7/lib/libz.so.1 is not an

          archive or the file could not be read properly.

  System error: Exec format error
```

I have a remote IBM i server which has two users.  The first user "gitUser" is used for my private Git repositories (headless).  I then have another user "sshUser" which is used to SSH in with and do my typical work.  I have SSH keys configured to simplify connections for both users and the "gitUser" ssh key doesn't require a password, so I can use it for automated scripting.

I have a private VCS repository included in my composer.json file for a project.  So long as I have the entry in the "repository" section I'm getting the above error.  This occurs even if I'm not `require`ing a package from the repository.

**Repository Entry:**

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "gitUser:/opt/git/myPackage.git"
    }
]
```

Composer on the IBM i is up to date at 1.7.2.

It's clear the issue lies with git and the inability to find a dependency in `libz.so.1`.

However, if I follow the chain of dependencies for the version of Git in my path, all the appropriate files exist with adequate permissions:

```
bash-4.4$ which git                                                   
/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/git                                                
bash-4.4$ dump -X64 -H /QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/git                         

/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/git:                                               

                        ***Loader Section***                          
                      Loader Header Information                       
VERSION#         #SYMtableENT     #RELOCent        LENidSTR           
0x00000001       0x000000df       0x0000433f       0x0000009d         

#IMPfilID        OFFidSTR         LENstrTBL        OFFstrTBL          
0x00000006       0x00044910       0x00000a18       0x000449ad         


                        ***Import File Strings***                     
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER       
0      /QOpenSys/pkgs/lib:/QOpenSys/usr/lib                           
1                                    libz.so.1           shr_64.o     
2                                    libiconv.so.2       shr_64.o     
3                                    libcrypto.so.1.0.0  shr_64.o     
4                                    libpthread.a        shr_xpg5_64.o
5                                    libc.a              shr_64.o     
bash-4.4$
```

I can confirm there are no permission failures through out all of this.  So this doesn't seem to be the result of inadequate permissions.  Also, I do not think the issue lies within the user profile `gitUser` as if I issue a `composer install` or `composer update` from another machine (with appropriate keys), everything works flawlessly.  So it seems to be specific to the IBM i and the `sshUser` profile.

I'm starting to think Composer is using a different `git` executable and the dependencies of that executable do not exist.  Though I assume Composer would just use my path.

**Note***: I tried specifying my LIBPATH in my `./.profile` with the following.  But it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
LIBPATH=/usr/local/zendphp7/lib
LIBPATH=$LIBPATH:/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib:/QOpenSys/usr/lib
export LIBPATH
```

When echoing:

```
bash-4.4$ echo $LIBPATH
/usr/local/zendphp7/lib:/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib:/QOpenSys/usr/lib
bash-4.4$
```

If I don't add the above to my `./.profile`, then `echo $LIBPATH` prints a blank line to screen.

**Solution:**
I just changed the symlink in the ZENDPHP7 directory structure to the repo version.  Alternatively you can manipulate your library path, but I couldn't figure out the proper way to do it on IBM i.

```
bash-4.4$ pwd
/usr/local/zendphp7/lib
bash-4.4$ ln -s /QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/libz.so.1 ./libz.so.1
bash-4.4$ ls -la /usr/local/zendphp7/lib/libz.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dl 0 56 Oct 11 14:21 /usr/local/zendphp7/lib/libz.so.1 -> /QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/libz.so.1
bash-4.4$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing something is off with your path when you do the install.  Is it maybe looking at the Zend PHP libraries rather than the expected ones in /usr/lib?

Notice that the errors shows a path of **/usr/local/zendphp7/lib/** libz.so.1(shr_64.o) while your git dump instead shows **/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib:/QOpenSys/usr/lib**.

Comment: Thank you, On IBM i, how would I view my current LIBPATH (or the equivalent on IBM i)?  I've tried `echo $LIBPATH` but it prints out a blank line to the screen.  Also, how could I manipulate my LIBPATH (or the equivalent on IBM i)?  I tried adding the following to my `~/.profile` but it seems to break most commands located in `/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/` :  `LIBPATH=$LIBPATH:/usr/local/zendphp7/lib` and then `export LIBPATH`

Comment: I updated my question with more information related to this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to an SSH session to test using bash on the IBM i but the problem is almost certainly that /usr/local/zendphp7/lib is using a different version of libz.so.1 than exists in /usr/lib.  You also have the zendphp path ahead of /usr/lib so its going to try and use that one because it found it first.  At the very least, I would try a test with the zendphp7 path removed entirely from my PATH and LIBPATH environment variables.  As far as resolving the dependency issue, without knowing your system it would be hard to give specifics.

Comment: As a continuing suggestion, you may need to update the composer project to build and link from the zendphp libraries rather than the ones included in the repo.  My guess is that it is building using the version in the repo but on install it is using the version in zendphp.  This is likely what is causing the conflict.